# Ejb return CustomClass from jar

Tags: java, maven, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I read this answer ([stack answer read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725196/remote-ejb-return-type))  but, If you could help me, explain if my situation described and drawn, as it should be solved.

I have a class in the war, that is Customclass(POJO) is of other project and it is loaded to the war project via maven (jar loaded into the war), but I want to my @remote ejb return a object of that class to my war project. (using EAP 7,ejb facade ->ejb )

[image: image of code]
thanks in advance,whatever comment.

[Remote EJB return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725196/remote-ejb-return-type/56225309#56225309)

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Updated** 
ok, I add to my project-lib and my project-impl  the dependency  like this on each pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifacname</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifacname</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in the other thread, your POJO should be available to your war (this is taken care of already) and to your EJB module (probably you will have to add this to your EJB projects pom). Create a method with the POJO return type in ejb interface and write the implementation in your EJB project. You will then write the caller to this new EJB method in the war project (Action/Controller/etc...).

---

For the build to be successful the POJO should be available to both the projects (WAR/EJB).

Comment: thanks for you comment, I update the both EJB projects,I describe it on the ask(updated),but I have this problem when try to compile a super project, this project joins all EJB and expose that in a container , the war is in other container. https://justpaste.it/1uj8r Please advice ;D

Comment: You are getting a NoClassDefFoundError - This means your class co.com.generacionmovil.mapas.componentes.LeafLet is available for compilation but not for runtime. Can you make sure that your POJO jar is available in the war...

Comment: thank you for you help, but I dont know where put the scope for the jar, at dependencyManagement or at dependencies or I must to configure  it at the pom of the jar, in this moment i can't try it, I have other tasks.

Comment: Here is a link that talks about it. https://coderanch.com/t/594897/ide/include-maven-dependencies-war-file